# Prove, that f is a linear map.

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry, normed-spaces, inner-products

$U,V$ - Euclidean spaces
$f:U \rightarrow V$
 $f(0)=0$
$ \forall _{u,v \in U}:d(f(u),f(v))=d(u,v)$

Prove that $f$ is a linear map.

I'm thinking about something like this:
$||f(u+v)|| =d(f(u+v),0) = d(u+v,0) = ||u+v|| = ||u- (-v) || = d(u,-v) = d(f(u),f(-v)) = ||f(u) - f(-v)||$
but does it equeal $||f(u) + f(v)||$?

Comment: Is $d(x,y) = \|x-y\|$?

Comment: Note that the generalization of this to an arbitrary real normed space (with an extra surjectivity assumption) is called the [Mazur-Ulam theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem), a recent short proof of which is given [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.2380). But the Euclidean structure simplifies the matter a lot.

Comment: @copper.hat I think it is, it's an euclidean space.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint** Prove that

$$||f(\alpha u+v)-\alpha f(u)-f(v)||^2=0$$

Comment: Good point and very funny hat. :D